# Git diff between string and file at specific revision

Tags: git

Is it possible to compute the diff between a versioned file (at a specific SHA) and its possibly future content, stored as a string?

For instance, something like:

`$ git diff -- file.txt@SHA "Future\ncontent\nof\nfile.txt"`

Comment: Is `Future\ncontent\nof\nfile.txt` simply a file on your filesystem?

Comment: no, just a string in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare versioned file(s) from different versions using `git diff`:

```
git diff SHA -- file.txt
```

Or you can compare unversioned files using `diff` or [`git diff --no-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt):

```
git diff --no-index file1.txt file2.txt
```

And you can compare an unversioned file with a string using [`<()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Process_Substitution) bashism:

```
diff file.txt <(echo -e "Future\ncontent\nof\nfile.txt")
```

But not both. That is, you cannot diff a versioned file with a string,
but can extract the versioned file the same way:

```
diff <(git cat-file -p $SHA:file.txt) <(echo -e "Future\ncontent\nof\nfile.txt")
```